# Is it possible to restore a database snapshot from a 64 bit system to a 32 bit one?

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.5, mariadb, snapshot

I would like to perform a restoration test on a snapshot backup of my MariaDB database using a test server running on a 32-bit OS. My production server is a 64-bit system. I would like to know if the architecture of the OS makes a difference to the database files. Both servers are running the same version of MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MyISAM [and] InnoDB data and log files are binary-compatible on all
>   platforms having the same floating-point number format.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html).

You can copy freely between those two platforms if you maintain the same vendor and version.

Obviously, the binary executables for 64 bits will not work on 32-bit.

Comment: That's good news. Thanks for the confirmation!